# Is it possible to count the number of items with the same ID across different months (like an intersect across aggregated months)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having hard time phrasing my question. I want to group by month, and then for each month, find how many accounts are the same between the N and N-1 month. So, specifically, I'm not comparing the aggregation (like total counts), I want to somehow count the `intersect` between the months.

So for example, this table:

```
date          id    

2020-01-01    123
2020-01-01    234
2020-01-01    345
2020-02-01    123
2020-02-01    345
2020-03-01    123
2020-03-01    456
```

I'm trying to produce a result like:

```
date          total   same 
2020-01-01    3       null -- no previous month with which to compare
2020-02-01    2       2
2020-03-01    2       1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm, count(*) as total,
       count(*) filter (where date_trunc('month', date) = date_trunc('month', prev_date) as same_as_prev_month
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Note:  This assume that ids have at most one row per month.  If rows can be duplicated, use `count(distinct)`:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm,
       count(distinct id) as total,
       count(distinct id) filter (where date_trunc('month', date) = date_trunc('month', prev_date) as same_as_prev_month
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try a self join aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.date,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(t2.id) AS same
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.date = t1.date - INTERVAL '1 month' AND
       t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY
    t1.date;
```

The idea here is to self join to bring each record in line with a matching `id` from the previous month, should such a match exist.  Note that this answer assumes that the `date` values would always be the first of the month.